# Proving that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{n+5}\right)$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I want to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\{{n^2 \over n+5}\}$ DNE. I thought I could try to do proof by contradiction:

Choose $\epsilon = 1,$ then there exist $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $$\left|{n^2 \over n+5} - L\right| < 1 \implies L- 1 < {n^2 \over n+5} \le {n^2 \over n} = n \le N < L + 1$$ which the natural numbers are not bounded, so the limit cannot possibly exist.

But this proof is flawed because how to I know that $${n^2 \over n+5} < L + 1 \implies {n^2 \over n} < L+ 1?$$

Is there something I'm missing here? I think maybe the contradiction lies on the otherside of the inequality, that $L - 1 < n$, but I don't see what the contradiction might be...

Comment: Don't use non-standard shortwriting: not all study in the same school...or even country...or even continent.

Comment: I am very sorry. I did not know this was not standard short-writing. Thanks @Dr.MV, as this solved my problem.

Comment: You can't assume if $\frac {n^2}{n+5} \le W$ that $\frac{n^2}{n} \le W$. You'll have to do something else.  If $\frac {n^2}{n+5} < L+1 = M$ then $n^2 < Mn + 5M$ so $n^2 - Mn + M^2/4 < 5M + M^2/4 = K$ so $(n- M/2)^2 <  K$.  But that is not true for any $n > \sqrt{K} + M/2$.

Comment: First at all ${n^2 \over n+5}= \frac{n}{1+\frac5n}$ then the limit is $\infty$. Do you mean for this the limit does not exist?

Comment: Yes, @pyrazolam, your way is not correct. There IS actually a flaw using your method! So just give up using someting like $\frac{n^2}{n+5}<\frac{n^2}{n}=n$. See my post for my way of this problem.

Comment: And for your second question, well, there is no any contradiction of the other side $L-1<\frac{n^2}{n+5}$! So just give up try to deduce some contradiction in that side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for any number $B>0$, however large, we have

$$\left|\frac{n^2}{n+5}\right|> B$$

whenever $n>\frac{B+\sqrt{B^2+20B}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n+5}$ exists, say, $\exists L\in\mathbb{R},~\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n+5}=L$.

Then by the definition of limit of sequence, we know that $$\forall\varepsilon>0~,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},~\forall n\geq N,~\left|\frac{n^2}{n+5}-L\right|<\varepsilon~~~~~~~~(\star)$$

However, we can simply see that when $n$ becomes bigger and bigger, the fraction 
$\frac{n^2}{n+5}$ will go to $\infty$(informally speaking). So the assumption we make have a contradiction. But how can we write down this in a rigorous manner?

By $(\star)$, let $\varepsilon=1$, then $\exists N_{0}\in\mathbb{N},~\forall n\geq N_{0},~|\frac{n^2}{n+5}-L|<1$. Let us observe the latter inequality:
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
&\left|\frac{n^2}{n+5}-L\right|<1\\
\Leftrightarrow& -1<\frac{n^2}{n+5}-L<1\\
\Leftrightarrow& -1+L<\underbrace{\frac{n^2}{n+5}<1+L}_{\text{may have trouble when $n$ is sufficiently big.}}
\end{alignat}$$

By intuition, when $n$ is big enough, $\frac{n^2}{n+5}$ can exceed 1+L. But how can we show that? You can think $1+L$ as a single value, so the next step you should do is to **derive the contradiction**, namely try to solve the inequality $$\frac{n^2}{n+5}\geq 1+L~~~~(\diamondsuit)$$ (for convenience, think as solving it in real numbers first).

And you get $n^2\geq(1+L)(n+5)$, then $n^2-(1+L)n-5(1+L)\geq0$. Since the coefficient of $n^2$ is positive(is $1$), then no matter the discrimanet of this inequality is, the inequality must have a solution of the form $(-\infty,\alpha]\cup[\beta,\infty)$ or all $\mathbb{R}$. Hence there exists a $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N_1$, $n$ satisfy the inequality $(\diamondsuit)$, hence not satisfying $\frac{n^2}{n+5}<1+L$. Then pick $N'=\max\{N_0, N_1\}$,

$$\left(\frac{N'^2}{N'+5}<1+L\right)\wedge\left(\frac{N'^2}{N'+5}\geq1+L\right)$$
 a contradiction.
Hence, the assumption is false, namely $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n+5}$ **does not exists**.